# How to install RVM on Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, localization, rvm

I try install RVM using [this](http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-ubuntu.html) tutorial. But I get en error on this step `$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`. I get this message:

```
oleg@olegx301a:~$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   184  100   184    0     0    330      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   331
100 22721  100 22721    0     0  30495      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 30495
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/1.26.11.tar.gz
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.26.11/1.26.11.tar.gz.asc
gpg: Signature made вт, 31-бер-2015 00:52:13 +0300 EEST using RSA key ID BF04FF17
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
Warning, RVM 1.26.0 introduces signed releases and automated check of signatures when GPG software found.
Assuming you trust Michal Papis import the mpapis public key (downloading the signatures).

GPG signature verification failed for '/home/oleg/.rvm/archives/rvm-1.26.11.tgz' - 'https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.26.11/1.26.11.tar.gz.asc'!
try downloading the signatures:

    gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3

or if it fails:

    command curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg --import -

the key can be compared with:

    https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc
    https://keybase.io/mpapis
```

Maybe problem is due to my localization - it is Ukraine. There is line in terminal output `gpg: Signature made вт, 31-бер-2015 00:52:13 +0300 EEST using RSA key ID BF04FF17` with `вт, 31-бер-2015` which means Tuesday, March 31.

Comment: You should try downloading the signatures the way it recommends. See how it responds

Comment: They go out of their way to give you the command to run. Have you tried that? This is just a message saying it won't install anything until you've loaded in the GPG key.

Comment: @OscillatingMonkey  and @tadman thanks. I just didn`t know what the heck it was asking me to install. Should i delete this theme?

Comment: leave it, I'm sure people always come across little issues like this one

Answer (score 2):

This is the command I use to install Ruby using RVM toolkit:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 && \
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby=1.9.3
```

You may change the Ruby version to whatever you need, for example `2.3-head`